# How should I render an object in multiple controllers in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coding-style

I have a single model that users can modify in many ways throughout my website.  At first,  I created methods for it using a controller for one set of views, eg:

```
#controller1.rb
def edit_object
end

def render_object
end
```

I could set up multiple controllers in the same way, but some (not all) of the logic in each controller is the same.  Should make one `main_object_controller` to manage the model and have other controllers call methods in `main_object_controller`, keep the methods in separate controllers, or have every method for every view modifying the model in `main_object_controller`?

Comment: Need some examples of how the modifications differ to provide a recommendation.  BUT, if it's big functional differences (like admin vs. standard user or different sets of fields), you should be creating different controllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a good time to learn about [Rails concerns](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html).

They are basically ruby modules where you can define methods that you need to reuse in multiple places; in addition, Rails 4 automatically loads all files in `app/models/concerns` and `app/controllers/concerns`.

For example, let's say you have a concern in `app/controllers/concerns/edit_methods`:

```
module EditMethods
  def edit_object
    # ...
  end

  def render_object
    # ...
  end
end
```

In order to use these functions inside your other controllers you just need to include the concern like this:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  include EditMethods

  def edit
    # you can call all methods defined in the concern
    edit_object

    # ...
  end
end
```